# Is there a CSS hack to get the following look from only 1 div?

Tags: css

The following is a picture from the mockup of a section of a webpage I'm creating.

[image: wut i need]

The part I'm having trouble with is the light grey box with the white border, inside the dark grey box; because all I have to work with is a single `div` that is spat out by my content management system. I would know how to do this if I had nested `div`s, but I don't have that (unless I want to add fancy `JavaScript`).

I made a JSFiddle that provides the basic setup of the problem at hand: http://jsfiddle.net/ytq3grwd/

Is this problem possible to solve with `CSS` only? If so, how?

Comment: you can also do this with a pseudo element

Answer (score 1):

You could use a border and box shadow:

```
#only-div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #E7E2E2;
    border: 10px solid #C8C5C5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ytq3grwd/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outline`:

```
#only-div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #E7E2E2;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: 10px solid #c8c5c5;    
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytq3grwd/3/)

[CanIUse - Outline](http://caniuse.com/#search=outline)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to use both a border and an outline.
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/ytq3grwd/1/)

```
#only-div
{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #E7E2E2;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    outline:10px solid #C8C5C5;     
}
```